# QTextEdit setting setLineWrapMode to NoWrap causes large delay

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using `QTextEdit` to display a Table.

When I am trying to disable line wrap by using `setLineWrapMode(qtw.QTextEdit.NoWrap)`, it takes a lot of time to display the table.

Is it the expected behavior? How can I reduce the delay?

Minimal working example

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        textedit = qtw.QTextEdit()
        textedit.setReadOnly(True)
        
        textedit.setLineWrapMode(qtw.QTextEdit.NoWrap) #Commenting this line removes the delay
        
        headers = ["#", "Name", "Address","Website"]
        cursor = textedit.textCursor()
        
        
        tableFormat = qtg.QTextTableFormat()
        table=cursor.insertTable(201, 4, tableFormat)
        
        for header in headers:
            cursor.insertText(header)
            cell=table.cellAt(cursor)
            format = cell.format()
            format.setBackground(qtg.QColor("#CCE8FF"))
            cell.setFormat(format)
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        
        for i in range(200):
            cursor.insertText(str(i+1))
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
            cursor.insertText('David')
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
            cursor.insertText('6th Lane, 4th street, 9th state')
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
            cursor.insertHtml('<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>')
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        
        
        self.setCentralWidget(textedit)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Put the `textedit.setLineWrapMode (qtw.QTextEdit.NoWrap)` line very last in the 
 `__init__` method.

Comment: wow that worked. Thanks a lot. If you put it as answer with some explanation, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in the loop `for i in range (200):`
every time the table changes, it checks that `QTextEdit.NoWrap` is respected. At the same time, apparently, it makes this installation across the entire table that currently exists.
Sorry for my bad english.

Put the `textedit.setLineWrapMode(qtw.QTextEdit.NoWrap)` line very last in the `__init__` method.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        textedit = qtw.QTextEdit()
        textedit.setReadOnly(True)
        
#        textedit.setLineWrapMode(qtw.QTextEdit.NoWrap) # Commenting this line removes the delay
        
        headers = ["#", "Name", "Address","Website"]
        cursor = textedit.textCursor()
        
        tableFormat = qtg.QTextTableFormat()
        table=cursor.insertTable(201, 4, tableFormat)
        
        for header in headers:
            cursor.insertText(header)
            cell=table.cellAt(cursor)
            format = cell.format()
            format.setBackground(qtg.QColor("#CCE8FF"))
            cell.setFormat(format)
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        
        for i in range(200):
            cursor.insertText(str(i+1))
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
            cursor.insertText('David')
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
            cursor.insertText('6th Lane, 4th street, 9th state')
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
            cursor.insertHtml('<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>')
            cursor.movePosition(qtg.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(textedit)
#        self.show()

        textedit.setLineWrapMode(qtw.QTextEdit.NoWrap)                    # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]